# Stock ICS email app refusing to auto-update or notifications

Tags: sync, email, notifications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.1, all other apps seem to sync and notifiy fine. The email app has the settings:

- Inbox update frequency: 5 mins
- Email notification: Checked

It doesn't appear to be syncing at all, however as soon as I open the app it goes and gets all the new emails from the point I last closed the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following settings enabled in Settings -> Account & Sync:

- Bakcground Data,
- Auto-sync
- 'Sync Gmail' inside your email account

Comment: I believe DanH is asking about the Email app, not Gmail.

Comment: True, but Email app appears to have exactly the same setting there which was turned off. I'll wait 5 minutes and make sure it worked, but I think we have a winner :D

Comment: Strange that this setting is not accessible from within the Email app interface though, at least as far as my endless manic button mashing can tell.

Comment: Hmmm, curiously this setting appears to have made no difference

Comment: OK finally seems to be working now